# isset() does not seem to work on an array

Tags: php, isset

I am working on an existing piece of PHP code and try to understand it in order to debug an issue:

```
echo "Got here !!!\n";
var_dump($aHeaders);
if (isset($aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'])) {
    echo "aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set\n";
    ...
} elseif (isset($aHeaders['SALESUNIT'])) {
    echo "aHeaders['SALESUNIT'] is set\n";
    ...
}
echo "Got there !!!\n";
```

and I get the following output:

```
Got here !!!
array(1) {  
 ["EMAIL,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONE,TITLE,DATEOFBIRTH,SALESUNIT,LANGUAGE,STATUS,IS_RESELLER,CUSTOMDATE,ADDRESS_1,ADDRESS_2,CITY,COUNTRY,ZIPCODE,"]=>
int(0) }
Got there !!!
```

I am no deep expert at PHP, but I believe I should see:

```
aHeaders['SALESUNIT'] is set
```

in the output. What is going wrong?

My PHP version is PHP 5.5.30 if it matters.

Comment: Your array actually only has 1 element in it and the data contained in it is a massive string, not an associative array. the isset() would only work if it was an associative array.

Comment: The `echo` is also incorrect because you forgot the `$`-sign in front of the variable.

Comment: If you need to check if SALESUNIT is a value in the comma-separated list, use the explode function, then in_array():

`$arrHeaders = explode(',', $aHeaders[0]);
if ( in_array( 'SALESUNIT', $arrHeaders ) {
  echo 'found';
} else {
  echo 'not there';
}`. Check the PHP documentation for [isset()](http://php.net/isset) and [in_array()](http://php.net/in_array)

Comment: @Chris Actually, having the `$` for `echo "aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set\n";` as in `echo "$aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set\n";` (if that's what you meant) would have thrown `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING)`. I originally thought that his array would have been treated as constants, but I was wrong and deleted my comment about it. Yet, the `$` could have been escaped `echo "\$aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set\n";` without throwing a parse error.

Comment: @Fred-ii- I meant to concatenate the variable with the string.

Comment: @Chris TBH Chris, I don't quite understand what you mean by that. If you meant by echoing the dollar sign as having an output of `$ string value etc.`, I don't see relevance, as they're not dealing with money here ;-) At best, `echo "$" . "aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set\n";` if that's what you meant. Output: `$aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set`

Comment: @Fred-ii-, hehe, no I meant `echo $aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] . "is set\n";`, but idk it may yield the same error anyway?

Comment: @Chris That ^ would yield `Notice: Undefined index: SALESCHANNEL`, least in what I could test with.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you currently have is this:

```
$arr1 = array('EMAIL,FIRSTNAME,LASTNAME,PHONE,TITLE,DATEOFBIRTH,SALESUNIT,LANGUAGE,STATUS');
```

isset() would only work if you have the following:

```
$arr2 = array(
    'EMAIL' => 'blah',
    'FIRSTNAME' => 'blah',
    'LASTNAME' => 'blah',
    'PHONE' => 'blah',
    'TITLE' => 'blah',
    'DATEOFBIRTH' => 'blah',
    'SALESUNIT' => 'blah',
    'LANGUAGE' => 'blah',
    'STATUS' => 'blah'
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the below code

```
echo "Got here !!!\n";
var_dump($aHeaders);
// get the keys to array
$array_keys = array_keys($aHeaders)
// explode the array keys with comma
$array_values = explode(',',$array_keys[0]);
if (in_array('SALESCHANNEL',$array_values)) {
    echo "aHeaders['SALESCHANNEL'] is set\n";
    ...
} elseif (in_array('SALESUNIT',$array_values)) {
    echo "aHeaders['SALESUNIT'] is set\n";
    ...
}
echo "Got there !!!\n";
```

Comment: Why should the OP try this? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.